# conjugacy between geodesic flows on 2-tori

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $(T_1,g_1)$ and $(T_2,g_2)$ be two flat tori of dimension 2 such that their geodesic flows are $C^0$-conjugated, is there an isometry between $(T_1,g_1)$ and $(T_2,g_2)$ ?

I emphasize the fact that I ask a $C^0$-conjugacy. In the paper of Croke mentioned below in the answer it is a $C^1$-conjugacy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is theorem C in:

Croke, Christopher B.(1-PA)
Rigidity for surfaces of nonpositive curvature. 
Comment. Math. Helv.  65  (1990),  no. 1, 150–169.

Comment: Thanks, but in this paper, it is a $C^1$-conjugacy and not a $C^0$-conjugacy, as I asked for.